# I am getting dependency failed issue when I start proxmox server. Internet is running in the machine but I am not able to access it

Tags: server, dependencies, mount, proxmox

[image]

I have checked whether the disk is being detected or not, and it is indeed being detected. I have also tried using commands like "systemctl restart," "systemctl default," and "exit" to attempt to resolve the issue and boot to the default settings, but the problem has not been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy,
First give root pwd
then make changes in a file

> /etc/fstab

and remove the entries from there then reboot you system it will boot normally.

Thanks me later